# Strictest possible IAM (permissions and bucket) policy required to work with Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

What is the smallest/strictest set of permissions required to set up a working app using Active Storage to work with Amazon S3?

To start with something that *isn't* great: `AmazonS3FullAccess`

[image]

Technically this works, but is *very* bad practice because the IAM now has *full* access (i.e. it can do anything) and gives access to *all* buckets on the account, including those that have nothing to do with the app! So we could say this *doesn't* adhere to the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

#### Question

Using AWS's JSON format, what's the strictest possible IAM policy to allow regular functioning of Active Storage (i.e. uploading, reading, deleting images etc). Or in other words, the permissions mentioned [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html):

> The core features of Active Storage require the following permissions: `s3:ListBucket`, `s3:PutObject`, `s3:GetObject`, and `s3:DeleteObject`.

For the purpose of this question, please assume the app uses just one bucket called `mybucket`

#### What I know so far

After a lot of googling/reading docs, I mostly find 'examples' that don't explicitly map S3 permissions to the exact ActiveStorage requirements. In any case, [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) the best I have found:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can confirm that it 'works' (the rails app can 'see' the images, add new ones, and delete them).

Because I have not set these many times in the past, I can't confirm whether it's refined like I want it to be, or if there's anything missing that could cause problems.

TL;DR, just after the IAM policy that allows full functionality with Active Storage and nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see how you can get more restricted without impacting functionality. You've limited it to only the necessary actions for the bucket you wish to manage.